# Getting a black screen when trying to play a movie

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

When i'm trying to play a movie on my iPhone, it isn't work. I dont know why.. searched here and all over the internet, try 5 different codes, but still can't get it to work. I'm new to Obj-C, so please be patient.

I just want the movie to play and when the movie is done, to exit the player. also, at the beginning I dont want it to show a black screen, I want to see the first frame of the video instead. is it possible?

```
-(void)playTheMovie
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"C061381" ofType:@"mp4" inDirectory:@""]];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[player view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]]; // Frame must match parent view
    [self.view addSubview:[player view]];
    [player play];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are messing up with the URL.

Check out Movie player sample project from apple

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html

Run it first to confirm its functionality and then

Replace its movie with yours and change the extension and path name in the code

if it works copy the code to your project..

Comment: I dont want it to be with Play and Pause buttons, I just want the 6 seconds movie to be played when I start the application and when he is over, I want it to disappear.

Comment: your current code was good...you were just messing up with the URL..if you want to dismiss movie too check MPMoviePlayerViewController class

Comment: but why the movie isn't running?

Comment: if the movie player can't load the url it won't play the movie..in the sample project did you see URL for resource of type method..you will have to do something like that too

Comment: actually this project is too complicated for me, can't you tell me how to run a .mp4 file when I enter the UIView and when the movie is done, it will close the Player?

Comment: ` [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:player];`  is the major thing you need to have so that you get a notification when  the movie player is finished.. i am myself learning it..so you might want to look into some tutorials online or post a new question..since i am not much experienced in it